# Docker контейнер на хосте и docker контейнер на docker-machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

Нужно связать два контейнера на разных хостах. Swarm-mode потянуть на одном хосте не могу. Не понимаю, как пробросить порты

Comment: дубликат (с уточнением): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/666609/178576