# Кластер hadoop на докер контейнерах

Tags: docker, hadoop, docker-machine

Нужен кластер hadoop на докер контейнерах, которые расположены на разных хостах. Swarm потянуть не получиться. Можно ли это реализовать без swarm мода?!
Указал порты для контейнера
[image]

Но потом, когда пытался обратиться к нему извне, появилась ошибка
[image]

Comment: [«выставляете» порт контейнера «наружу» хост-машины](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) и подключаетесь к нему извне. естественно, внутри контейнера какой-то процесс должен слушать этот порт.

Comment: это ваш вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/666578/178576?

Comment: да, но после выставления портов и попытки обратиться к нему, появляется ошибка 
Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 80: В соединении отказано

Comment: пожалуйста, внесите всю необходимую информацию в текст вопроса (нажав [edit])

Comment: возможно дело в том, что у хадупа консоль вертится не на порту `80`, а на `8088`? разворачиваете просто Hadoop или Hortonworks Data Platform (судя по имени последнее всё-таки)?

Comment: Удалось найти решение? Собираюсь развернуть Hadoop, собираю информацию.